# LLVM How to detect when a specific ASM instruction sequence is generated

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, code-generation

I am compiling my C program using llvm. I want to know if a particular assembly sequence is generated and if generated, which source code line it is associated with. For example , i want to log every time `push %eax` instruction is generated. Is there any way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others stumble upon a similar problem.

The place I looked at was LLVMs backend code. In particular i was concerned with X86 assembly generation.

There are two main areas to modify and add your tests.

1. `ASMPrinter` class at `lib/CodeGen/ASMPrinter/ASMPrinter.cpp` which has different emit functions to deal with functions, basic blocks etc. Go through them. These functions iterate through each machine instructions `MI` which has functions like `getOperand()` and `getOpCode()` to check specific instructions as per requirement.

Each specific opcode and the actual instructions are specified in target specific files eg.`lib/Target/X86/X86GenInstrInfo.inc`

2. The above functions in turn call the target specific subclass functions. In my case they were X86AsmPrinter and similar classes.

To poke around add log statments such as

```
errs()<<"Opcode is "<<MI.getOpcode()<<"\n";
MI.dump();
```

and you can see these error messages when running `llc file.bc`

Hope it helps